# LUA: performance/efficiency of chaining functions

Tags: function, performance, lua

I was always under the impression that chaining functions in LUA (version 5.1) would perform worse than localizing it first and then calling the next function.

Am I just wrong or is my simple benchmark incorrect?

```
local clock = os.clock
local plugin = {}

function plugin:Test()
    return { SubTest = function() return "hello" end }
end

collectgarbage(); collectgarbage()
local start = clock()
for i=1, 1000000 do
    plugin:Test():SubTest()
end
print(clock() - start, collectgarbage("count") / 1024)

collectgarbage(); collectgarbage()
local start = clock()
for i=1, 1000000 do
    local module = plugin:Test()
    module:SubTest()
end
print(clock() - start, collectgarbage("count") / 1024)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> chaining functions in LUA would perform worse than localizing it first and then calling the next function

That's true only if you use the local (cached) value multiple times.

> is my simple benchmark incorrect?

Both loops in your benchmark get compiled to (almost) identical Lua bytecodes, so their performance must be equal.